# AzureSpringBootRequestHandler can't find function

Tags: java, function, spring-boot, azure-functions

I have a simple Spring Boot Function app with just 2 endpoints. Both produce a `Exception: IllegalStateException: No function defined error` with the following stacktrace:

```
[23/03/2020 14:16:57] 2020-03-23 11:16:57.455  WARN 4788 --- [pool-2-thread-5] c.f.c.c.BeanFactoryAwareFunctionRegistry : !!! Failed to discover function 'UserPublish' in function catalog. Function available in catalog are: [userGet, userPublish, functionRouter]
[23/03/2020 14:16:57]   at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.handler.InvocationRequestHandler.execute(InvocationRequestHandler.java:10)
[23/03/2020 14:16:57]   at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.handler.MessageHandler.handle(MessageHandler.java:45)
[23/03/2020 14:16:57]   at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.JavaWorkerClient$StreamingMessagePeer.lambda$onNext$0(JavaWorkerClient.java:92)
[23/03/2020 14:16:57]   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
[23/03/2020 14:16:57]   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[23/03/2020 14:16:57]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[23/03/2020 14:16:57]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[23/03/2020 14:16:57]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[23/03/2020 14:16:57] Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No function defined
[23/03/2020 14:16:57]   at org.springframework.cloud.function.context.AbstractSpringFunctionAdapterInitializer.apply(AbstractSpringFunctionAdapterInitializer.java:184)
[23/03/2020 14:16:57]   at org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.azure.AzureSpringBootRequestHandler.handleRequest(AzureSpringBootRequestHandler.java:83)
[23/03/2020 14:16:57]   at org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.azure.AzureSpringBootRequestHandler.handleRequest(AzureSpringBootRequestHandler.java:79)
[23/03/2020 14:16:57]   at com.mrlima.app.handler.azure.UserHandler.publish(UserHandler.java:42)
```

As you can see, the only difference between what it is trying to discover and what is in the catalog is the case of the first letter.
Not sure if this is really the root cause, but I wonder why it's doing that since I have defined my handler as the following:

```java
public class UserHandler extends AzureSpringBootRequestHandler<User, User> {

    @FunctionName("UserGet")
    public User get(@HttpTrigger(name = "request", methods = { HttpMethod.GET,
            HttpMethod.POST }, authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS, route = "users") HttpRequestMessage<Optional<User>> request,
            ExecutionContext context) {

        // implementation

        return handleRequest(user, context);
    }

    @FunctionName("UserPublish")
    public User publish(@HttpTrigger(name = "request", methods = {
            HttpMethod.POST }, authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS, route = "users/pub") HttpRequestMessage<User> request,
            ExecutionContext context) {

        context.getLogger().info(String.format("Request to publish user with data %s", request.getBody()));

        return handleRequest(request.getBody(), context);
    }
```

And my actual functions are

```java
public class UserGet implements Function<User, User> {

    @Override
    public User apply(User user) {
        return new User(String.format("Hello %s", user.getName()));
    }
}

public class UserPublish implements Function<User, User> {

    @Override
    public User apply(User user) {
        return new User(String.format("Published user record %s", user.getName()));
    }
}
```

To make things a bit more weird, this was working when I had only the `UserGet` function. After I have added the `UserPublish` it started to show this error...

I got this project in this [repo](https://github.com/murilorl/azure-services/tree/master/functions/java/azfunc-spring-app).

Any insight here is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an `@Bean(name="UserGet")` and `@Bean(name="UserPublish")` as class level annotations in your function classes. It works without this with only one class because there is nothing to resolve. With more than one function class you have to "tie" them together by name.

Earnie!